# Block every USB but one Windows 7 Registry

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-registry, blocking

I want to disable all new plugged in USB Sticks by a User, but want to keep my only one Stick still accessable.

For example I plug my "Master"-USB in and I can transfer Data to it. Another user plugges his/her own USB in and it would be disabled.

Can I do this with Registry?

Regards, 
Janik

Comment: This can be done through a group policy.  You should be aware the of modifying a device to appear to be your "Master" USB device is easily performed.